# How to shard a Set?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud, scalability, sharding

Could you help me with one thing? Imagine I have a simple RESTful microserver with one `GET` method which simply responds with a random `String`.

I assemble all the strings in a `ConcurrentHashSet<String>` that holds all answers.

There is a sloppy implementation below, the main thing is that the `Set<String>` is a fail-safe and can be modified simultaneously.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private final StringService stringService;

    private final CacheService cacheService;

    public Controller(final StringService stringService, final CacheService cacheService) {
        this.stringService = stringService;
        this.cacheService = cacheService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String get() {
        final String str = stringService.random();
        cacheService.add(str);
        return str;
    }

}


public class CacheService {

    private final Set<String> set = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    public void add(final String str) {
        set.add(str);
    }

}
```

While you are reading this line my endpint is being used by 1 billion people.
I want to shard the cache. Since my system is heavily loaded I can't hold all the strings on one server. I want to have 256 servers/instances and uniformly distribute my cache utilizing `str.hashCode()%256` function to determine on each server/instance should a string be kept.

Could you tell me what should I do next?
Assume that currently, I have only running locally Spring Boot application.

Comment: *Could you tell me what should I do next?* **What** do you mean? You seem to have all the answers.

Comment: Hi Elliot, I mean literally, which further steps should I take?

Comment: At my knowledge you can't directly share a object throw multiple instance of your service to do this you must use a way to "serialize" or store this object throw a data base (sql /nosql etc.)  by this way your diffrent stateless server instance will be able to share this data

Comment: I don't even see a `Map` in your question, so your question is beyond unclear.

Comment: Elliot, fixed, just finished Grokking the System Design Interview course and they always advise to have a HashMap as in-memory storage

Comment: you can use @Cachable annotation which helps you to do what you want  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial

Comment: Hi Jonathan, no, I want to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.org/), it is open source and has proved useful for me in a case where i wanted to share data among multiple instances of my application. The In-memory data grid provided by hazelcast might just be the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Vicky, this is what Hazelcast is made for. It's a single jar, a couple lines of code and instead of a HashMap, you have an IMap, which is an extension of HashMap, and you're good to go. All the distribution, sharding, concurrency, etc is done for you. Check out:

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.1/manual/html-single/index.html#map

Answer (score 0):

Try follow codes.But,it is a bad way,you best use `Map` to cache your data in one instance.If you need to create distributed application,try distributed catche service like Redis.

```
class CacheService {

        /**
         * assume read operation is more frequently than write operation
         */
        private final static List<Set<String>> sets = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

        static {
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                sets.add(ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet());
            }
        }

        public void add(final String str) {
            int insertIndex = str.hashCode() % 256;
            sets.get(insertIndex).add(str);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi, and where and how should I point to store each Set on each server?